# Stuck solving a minimum problem

Tags: maxima-minima, dynamic-programming, programming

I was doing some studying to improve my chances for an upcoming programming test, and I came across this problem. Trying to understand this leaves me quite confused about the correct answer and algorithm I need to develop. Any guidance someone can give me in how to go about this?

---

You are hosting a sporting match with *N* athletes, and there are various events in the competition such as weight lifting and running. Each event is worth 1 or 2 points.

The scoreboard shows that the *i*th player has a score of *C*<sub>i</sub>.
Note that *C*<sub>i</sub> is a positive integer equal to the sum of the point values of all the events they have completed.

The scoreboard does have any other details, such as the number of competitive events, nor their point values.

Write a program to determine the minimum possible number of competitive events in the sporting match for *N* athletes of an array of *C* scores.

**Example**
If the scoreboard says 1  2  3  4  5  6 and there are 6 athletes, then the minimum number of competitive events should be **4**

---

I try to solve this and keep thinking the answer should be '3' - for the events to either be 1 or 2 points, then for someone to get a 6 (the highest score) the fastest way would be 2+2+2 = 6 or 3 events. If there are 3 events, then it means every other score on the board would be satisfied (1 means someone got a 1 on the first event, but didn't yet do the other 2 events. a 2 means the athlete either completed one or two events, with either a 2 or two 1's, etc). What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that each event is worth the same number of points to each athlete if they complete, and 0 otherwise. IE In this example, we need 1 event of 1 point, and 3 events of 2 points, in order to get $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \}$. In your thought process, you had 3 events giving 1-2 points each to the atheletes, in order to get that set. IE With 3 events, the athlete with 6 points needs $\{2, 2, 2\}$. Wheras the athelete with 1 point needs $\{1, 0, 0\}$, so it can't be done.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinLin but why is {1,0,0} not a valid allocation? If they say the answer is 4, then wouldn't it be {1,0,0,0} ? What makes {1,0,0} incorrect but {1,0,0,0} correct?

Comment: As I said, "(my guess is that) each event is worth the same number of points to each athlete if they complete". If you have 3 events that are worth 1, 2, 2, then you can get 1 point, but not 6 points. If you have 3 events that are worth 2, 2, 2, then you can get 6 points, but not 1 point.

Comment: Thanks so much, perhaps you are right! If so, any thoughts on an algorithmic approach to take to solve?

Comment: The answer seems a bit obvious to me. Doesn't need an algorithmic approach, just reason it out.